# executing payment without storing the paymetId in session but database

Tags: paypal

I'm using the examples in the paypal-php-sdk and setting up payments. It works fine and I'm getting the redirect URL and I'm able to make the payment.

In the example the PaymentId is stored in the session, and later in the `executePayment.php` retrieved. In the comments it says to store this, off course in a database.

But how can I link this PaymentId to the return values givin by the paypal api?

When the payment is approved I'm sent back to my webstore with this parameters:

```
ExecutePayment.php?success=true&token=EC-xxxxxx&PayerID=AXxxxxx
```

How can I link the token-payerID to my PaymentID? So I don't have to store it in a Session? For instance is it possible to get the ec-token during the build of the payment?

Comment: I think you usually send an invoice with the payment to Paypal. That invoice is stored in your datebase before going to Paypal. And when Paypal returns to your website it should give you back the invoice with wich you can then track what payment it is in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be very simple!

In the return url parameter you just give the url an query string. Pretty simple:

```
$returnUrl = 'executePayment.php?orderId=234'
```

Paypal then automagically adds the token and payer-id to the return URL.